# Cant connect to webservice with simple php test script

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm trying to connect to this webservice: http://magnetledavet.com/GetStuffed/Service.asmx?WSDL

I'm using this simple script to test it but I don't seem to be getting anything back whatsoever and I'm not sure about what's causing the problem.

Here is my test script can anybody see whats wrong?

```
<?php

if(!class_exists("SoapClient")){ die("Catch"); }


$client = new SoapClient('http://magnetledavet.com/GetStuffed/Service.asmx?WSDL',     array('soap_version'  => SOAP_1_2));
echo "test";
//var_dump($client->__getFunctions());


echo("Dump Start:<br>");
var_dump($client->SendOrder( array(
                               "merchant_id"    => 1, 
                               "order_id"       => "445",
                               "username"       => "test",
                               "password"       => "test123",
                               "products"       => array( 
                                                    array("qty" => 1, "product_id" =>"1", "product_name" => "Product Test 1", "price" =>15), 
                                                    array("qty" => 1, "product_id" =>"2", "product_name" => "Product Test 2", "price" =>25)
                                                        ),
                               "order_details"  => "Dont add cheese !!",
                               "amount"         => 40,
                               "point"          => 40,
                               "payment_type"   => "test",
                               "webdate"        => date("Y-m-d").'T'.date("H:i:s"),
                               "customer_name"  => "Steve Jobs",
                               "address"        => "4th Floor Grosvenor House, 1 High Street Edgware",
                               "state"          => "test",
                               "phone"          => "+447711111111",
                               "postcode"       => "HA8 7TA",
                               "email"          => "abc@abc.com",
                               "delivery_time"  => date("Y-m-d").'T'.date("H:i:s"),
                               "delivery_notes" => "test"
                               ) 
                        ));
//var_dump($client->__soapCall("SendOrder", array( 'merchant_id' => 1 )));
print("Dump End:<br>");

 ?>
```

getting the following soap error :SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'magnetledavet.com/GetStuffed/Service.asmx?WSDL'; : failed to load external entity "magnetledavet.com/GetStuffed/Service.asmx?WSDL"; in C:\xampp\htdocs\get_stuffed\webservice.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\get_stuffed\webservice.php(6): SoapClient->SoapClient('magnetle...';, Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\get_stuffed\webservice.php

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is the variable dump showing?

Comment: there is nothing showing at all no errors or no dump.

Comment: Surely the SOAP client has some debugging options though? http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php `On error, a call to a SOAP function can cause PHP to throw exceptions or return a SoapFault object if exceptions are disabled. To check if the function call failed to catch the SoapFault exceptions, check the result with is_soap_fault().`

Comment: This is my first time using php soap so I'm not entirely sure. Everything after this line does nothing even the echo test $client = new SoapClient('http://magnetledavet.com/GetStuffed/Service.asmx?WSDL',     array('soap_version'  => SOAP_1_2));

Comment: Is error reporting enabled? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: error reporting was off I turned it on to find this error:Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://magnetledavet.com/GetStuffed/Service.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://magnetledavet.com/GetStuffed/Service.asmx?WSDL" in C:\xampp\htdocs\get_stuffed\webservice.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\get_stuffed\webservice.php(6): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://magnetle...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\get_stuffed\webservice.php on line 6

Comment: Consider pasting that into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct. The problem is with the web server which is serving the WSDL file. It turns out that it won't send it to you if you down supply a `user-agent` and a `keep-alive` header. I think this cannot be set via SoapClient. But still you can download the wsdl manualy. I created a script which will download the WSDL file via cURL once every hour. The SoapClient will use locally cached file.

```
if(!is_file('test.wsdl') || filemtime('test.wsdl') < time()-3600) {

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://magnetledavet.com/GetStuffed/Service.asmx?WSDL");
  $header = array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0'
  , 'Connection: keep-alive');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  $wsdl = curl_exec($ch);
  file_put_contents('test.wsdl', $wsdl);
}

$client = new SoapClient('test.wsdl',     array('soap_version'  => SOAP_1_2));
```

Try removing user agent to see that the WSDL file cannot be retrieved without it.

Comment: Hmm seems to working now with my original code. Must have been an issue with the webservice itself.